# getWidth not returning different value after scaling

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to find what I'm missing when using setScaleX.

```
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Start at 60
            Log.d("test", "Before"+String.valueOf(iv.getWidth()));
            iv.setScaleX((float) .5);
            // Still at 60 after scale
            Log.d("test", "After"+String.valueOf(iv.getWidth()));
        }

    });
```

I would of thought the width would have become 30. How do I get the value of the width after scaling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can solve it by multiply  by `scale x or y`

```
 final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Start at 60
            Log.d("test", "Before"+String.valueOf(iv.getWidth()* iv.getScaleX()));
            iv.setScaleX((float) .5);
            // Still at 60 after scale
            Log.d("test", "After"+String.valueOf(iv.getWidth()* iv.getScaleX()));
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`getWidth()` returns the width **before** transforms are applied  to the view (`setScaleX`, etc...). So this is expected. This is hinted by the documentation of [getDrawingRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect(android.graphics.Rect)):

```
 These bounds do not account for any transformation properties currently set on the view, 
 such as setScaleX(float) or setRotation(float).
```