# Android ObjectAnimator: Padding after scale animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview, scale

I have a problem with scaleX and scaleY animations using ObjectAnimator.

At the end of animation, the Drawable inside is resized but not the size of the border of the ImageView.

Schema of my problem : [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N9yM.png)

**XML ImageView code**

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/avenger"
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/vaisseau"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/santeBouclier"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**Animation code:**

```
        ImageView avenger = (ImageView)this.jeu.findViewById(R.id.vaisseau);

        AnimatorSet resizeAvenger = new AnimatorSet();
        ObjectAnimator animResizeX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(avenger, "scaleX", 1f, 0.3f);
        animResizeX.setDuration(4000);
        ObjectAnimator animResizeY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(avenger, "scaleY", 1f, 0.3f);
        animResizeY.setDuration(4000);
        resizeAvenger.playTogether(animResizeX, animResizeY);
        resizeAvenger.start();
```

I think my problem is here :

**Before the animation :**
avenger.getScaleX() = 1
avenger.getWidth() = 190

**After the animation :**
avenger.getScaleX() = 0.3
avenger.getWidth() = 190

Comment: apply your animation to the container.

Comment: I think I have badly explained my problem, by "container" I mean the border of the ImageView.    
**Before the animation :**  
avenger.getScaleX() = 1  
avenger.getWidth() = 190    


**After the animation :**  
avenger.getScaleX() = 0.5  
avenger.getWidth() = 190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiply width and scale factor as said here:

[getWidth not returning different value after scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675601/getwidth-not-returning-different-value-after-scaling)